# Different output for nb_NO and nn_NO when using NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

Why isn't both nb_NO and nn_NO formatted in the same way? What am I missing?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void printPrice(NSNumber *price, NSLocale *locale)
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    numberFormatter.locale = locale;
    NSString *string = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@120];
    printf("%s\n", [string UTF8String]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        {
            NSString *identifier = @"nb_NO";
            NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier];
            printPrice(@120, locale);
        }
        {
            NSString *identifier = @"nn_NO";
            NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier];
            printPrice(@120, locale);
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
kr 120,00
120,00 kr
```

Comment: Because someone at Apple decide to code it that way, really I don't see how anyone could answer this. If it is not correct in your eye you should fill in a bug report with apple.

Comment: Well, I'm interested in knowing how other people handle this problem. I assume it is a bug and will file a radar.